# Symfony3 Facebook Login - redirect_uri URL gets converted to relative

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, symfony, facebook-login

I am trying to implement facebook login for a web-app.
Here is the FacebookConnect.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\GiftBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator;

class FacebookConnectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/connect/facebook", name="connect_facebook")
     */
    public function connectFacebookAction(Request $request)
    {

        // redirect to Facebook
        $redir = $this->generateUrl('connect_facebook_check', array(), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
        $facebookOAuthProvider = $this->get('app.facebook_provider');
        $url = $facebookOAuthProvider->getAuthorizationUrl([
            // these are actually the default scopes
            'scopes' => ['public_profile', 'email'],
            'redirect_uri' => [$redir],
        ]);
        return $this->redirect($url);
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/connect/facebook-check", name="connect_facebook_check")
     */
    public function connectFacebookActionCheck()
    {
        // will not be reached!
    }
}
```

When I hit the button which triggers the connectFacebookAction function I get the FB Error *The redirect_uri URL must be absolute*. It's like it ignores the absolute URL I have given him in the parameters.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Is the authorization URL changing in any circumstances or remains the same for the app? Could I just hardcode it in until I figure out how to fix this?

**EDIT2**: I figured out why the URL is relative and not absolute.
Here is my services configuration:

```
services:
    app.facebook_provider:
        class: League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Facebook
        arguments:
            -
                clientId: %facebook_app_id%
                clientSecret: %facebook_app_secret%
                graphApiVersion: v2.8
                redirectUri: "@=service('router').generate('connect_facebook_check', {}, true)"
```

**How do I do an absolute URL generation from a route in services?**

Comment: FB is probably right, dump out the values and  hard code the url to test

Comment: @Dagon    True, Facebook is right. I dumped `$redir` and it is a real absolute URL. but after it gets goes in as a parameter for `getAuthorizationUrl` it goes back to a relative one. I checked the query in the browser and it no longer is absolute. I also tried manually inputting the absolute value of the redir and then it works, so what is wrong that it gets turned back into a relative one?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using version 1.x of league/oauth2-client (you can check in composer.lock)? That [ignores the redirect_uri in getAuthorizationUrl](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/blob/1.4.2/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php#L360) and uses the one you pass in the constructor. If you're using that version, change the definition for app.facebook_provider to read

```
redirectUri: "@=service('router').generate('connect_facebook_check', {}, 0)"
```

Note the 0 instead of true. [The UrlGeneratorInterface constants have changed in 2.8](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGeneratorInterface.php#L37).

Comment: I have `version 2.2.1`. If I replace `true` with `0`, I get this error: `bio field is deprecated for versions v2.8 and higher`

Comment: I highly doubt that that error is related to the change in the service definition.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that you're missing the request context in your service. Have a look at:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/request_context.html

You could pass it the request and then do something like:

```
$context = new RequestContext();
$context->fromRequest($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest());
$this->router->setContext($context);
$this->router->generate('connect_facebook_check', array(), RouterInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

Comment: Where is the ` $url = $facebookOAuthProvider->getAuthorizationUrl` in this case? It is not clear, how to modify `connectFacebookAction`

Comment: regardless of age, feel free to answer any unanswered question